# Change mouse coordinates

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, variables, mouse, coordinates

I want to change the mouse coordinates in my code. How I can do this? The coordinates are sent to Flash from a touch screen program and I want to define those coordinates to my mouse pointer inside the flash and then use all mouse functionality. It seems easy but I don't know how.
For example I want to do something like `mouseX = 200;` or `mouseY = var001;` and ..
.. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`mouseX` and `mouseY` are read-only properties of `DisplayObject`.

[See here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#mouseX)

Comment: I know, I cann`t change them .. : ( ,,

Comment: Sorry! But you could try and emulate the mouse with your own graphic and position that instead.. Would just be extremely tricky and probably not worth your time (you'd have to make your own click events, etc).

Comment: Yeah , I know that I can make a fake mouse pointer and define the coordination, but in that case I lose all mouse eventListeners and mouse functionalities which are pretty handy. Is there any other solution or solutions?

Comment: Not really, your project will have to cater for the restrictions that you're bound to by Flash.

Comment: Yeah, I guess allowing something like this could be considered a security violation by a lot of people, and they could be annoyed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing it's possible to set mouseX in AS3. But if you run your app in browser it's possible to "move" mouse in javascript, look [enter link description here](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-94382.html). But I don't think your users will like it :-)

Comment: That link seems to further back not being able to move the mouse with code? Haha.

Comment: @MartyWallace,anyway it's possible to change mouse coordinates with JS